# ::slotted() CSS pseudo-element with Tailwind

Tags: css-selectors, tailwind-css, web-component

I want to use `::slotted()` CSS pseudo-element with Tailwind, Tailwind supports most of pseudo-elements (`::before`, `::after`...), but it seems `::slotted` is not among them.
Is it possible to add support for `::slotted()` CSS pseudo-element by editing a config?

I tried applying `slotted:mb-md` class to  element and it does not work, looked for docs on how to add support for more pseudo-element, but didn't find anything

Comment: Add more code in an minimal example explaining what you want to do. You are now asking "I sticked a fork in it and the fork doesn't work"

Comment: Why don't you place the classes directly in your `slot`? Why do you need a selector here?